# Understanding the reason behind 'RuntimeError: leaf variable has been moved into the graph interior'

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to understand pytorch and how autograd works in it. I tried creating a tensor by filling it with values from other tensors and then checking the gradients. However, I am running into `RuntimeError: leaf variable has been moved into the graph interior` if I don't set `requires_grad` equal to `False`.

code:

```
x = torch.ones(3,5,requires_grad=True)

y = x+2

z = y*y*3

out1 = z.mean()
out2 = 2*z.mean()

outi = torch.empty(2,requires_grad=True)

outi[0] = out1
outi[1] = out2

outi.backward(torch.tensor([0.,1.]))
```

output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-1000fc52a64c> in <module>
     13 outi[1] = out2
     14 
---> 15 outi.backward(torch.tensor([0.,1.]))

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    183                 products. Defaults to ``False``.
    184         """
--> 185         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
    186 
    187     def register_hook(self, hook):

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
    123         retain_graph = create_graph
    124 
--> 125     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
    126         tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
    127         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag

RuntimeError: leaf variable has been moved into the graph interior
```

however, I can change the `requires_grad` to `False` and it will all work just fine

```
x = torch.ones(3,5,requires_grad=True)

y = x+2

z = y*y*3

out1 = z.mean()
out2 = 2*z.mean()

outi = torch.empty(2,requires_grad=False)

outi[0] = out1
outi[1] = out2

outi.backward(torch.tensor([0.,1.]))
```

output:

```
empty. it worked
```

Can somebody please help me understand what happened under the hood and, what changed with setting `require_grad` to True that resulted in this behavior? Thank you for reading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Intro

First, definition of what a `leaf` variable in PyTorch is, you can check [official documentation for `tensor.is_leaf`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.Tensor.is_leaf) (emphasis mine):

> All Tensors that have `requires_grad` which is `False` will be leaf
> Tensors by convention.
>
> **For Tensors that have `requires_grad` which is `True`, they will be
> leaf Tensors if they were created by the user. This means that they
> are not the result of an operation and so `grad_fn is None`.**

So let's see how this looks for `outi` variable in original code. Immediately after creation, running this snippet:

```
outi = torch.empty(2, requires_grad=True)
print(outi.is_leaf, outi.grad_fn, outi.requires_grad)
```

gives:

```
True, None, True
```

as it was created by user and there is no previous operation creating it so it should be the second bolded case from the above citation.

Now this line:

```
outi[0] = out1
outi[1] = out2
```

Uses two nodes **which are not leafs** and are part of the graph which goes back to `x` (which is the only leaf in it). By doing this `outi` is also part of the original `x` graph and would have to be backpropagated through, yet you specified it as a leaf (more on that later), which cannot be backpropagated through (by the definition they either **don't require gradient** or **are created by user**). Version of `outi` as `leaf` was already put on graph, after above assignment, this snippet:

```
print(outi.is_leaf, outi.grad_fn, outi.requires_grad)
```

changes to:

```
False <CopySlices object at 0x7f2dfa83a3d0> True
```

### Error

Now, I agree it's a pretty uninformative error given that changing `requires_grad=False` **does not make it non-leaf variable** (`requires_grad=False` is implicit):

```
outi = torch.empty(2)
print(outi.is_leaf, outi.grad_fn, outi.requires_grad)
# > True None False
```

But this tensor could be "upgraded" to non-leaf tensor if you use assignment as you did **without breaking the expected behaviour**.

Why? Because you implicitly (or explicitly in case of your code) said **you don't need gradient for this variable** and **PyTorch retains gradient only for leaf variables (unless you specify `.retain_grad` for specific `tensor`) due to memory optimization**. So the only change here would be it will no longer be a leaf, but **this would not break promises as `.grad` would be `None` anyway**.

If you were to have `requires_grad=True` as you originally did you could, reasonably, according to PyTorch semantics, think that this:

```
outi.grad
```

Will give you a `tensor` with gradient. But if this `requires_grad=True` tensor were to be changed to non-leaf tensor, then, by definition it wouldn't have this field (as non-leaf tensors have `.grad=None`).

To me it seems like a design decision on their part to avoid confusion with `requires_grad=True` and breaking expected user experience.

**BTW.** If they were to disallow `leaf` variables inside graph then operation which works fine now (`requires_grad=False`) should be disallowed as well. But as `requires_grad=False` is implicit and often used (creating tensors or something like you did) it seems not to be to much of a stretch to allow it. Disallowing it would be much more severe. On the other hand if you specify `requires_grad=True` it could be assumed you know better what you are doing and **really need that gradient here**.

**BTW2.** This explanation might be a stretch but hopefully will shed some light. I haven't found anything official regarding this error (admittedly though I didn't dig too deep).

Some resources [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/leaf-variable-has-been-moved-into-the-graph-interior/18679/13), [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/leaf-variable-was-used-in-an-inplace-operation/308/2) (this one is important, someone was asking for justification of some design decisions though didn't get one AFAIK).

### Comments

#### Comment 1

> I think the requires_grad is getting inherited from the slice and also
> .grad is available.

Yes, it has `requires_grad` as `True` also as it's part of the graph now, **BUT** `grad` is not available as it is no longer a leaf. Printing `outi.grad` after `backward` gives you `None` and the following warning:

> UserWarning: The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor
> is being accessed. Its .grad attribute won't be populated during
> autograd.backward(). If you indeed want the gradient for a non-leaf
> Tensor, use .retain_grad() on the non-leaf Tensor. If you access the
> non-leaf Tensor by mistake, make sure you access the leaf Tensor
> instead. See github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/30531 for more
> informations.

So the `.grad` attribute is `None` anyway as user would expect giving `requires_grad=False` as creation argument. User could expect gradient to be not `None` if he was to set `requires_grad=True` and that's when PyTorch raises the error, IMO due to possible inconsistency with user expectation in that case.

#### Comment 2

For example:

```
a = torch.ones(2,requires_grad=False)
b = 2*a
b.requires_grad=True
print(b.is_leaf) #True
```

I have changed your code a little to go through it step by step:

```
a = torch.ones(2, requires_grad=False)
print(a.is_leaf) # True
```

We should start with `a` here, `a` is a leaf according to docs as:

> All Tensors that have requires_grad which is False will be leaf
> Tensors by convention.

```
b = a * 2
print(b.is_leaf)
```

Now `b` is `leaf` as it does not require gradient (because `a` does not need a gradient it doesn't have to be backpropagated through this branch). Manipulating tensors with `requires_grad=False` creates tensors which do not `require_grad` otherwise it would be wasteful and non-sensical to turn it on.

```
b.requires_grad = True
print(b.is_leaf)
```

Now this one returns `True` as well. Once again, docs wording might not be the best here (as I've stated before), but (my additions in bold):

> For Tensors that have requires_grad which is True **(our case now)**
> they will be leaf Tensors if they were created by the user **(debatable about creation here as you have modified the existing one, indeed)**. This means that they are not the result of an operation and so grad_fn is None **(this one IMO clarifies the previous point)**

About clarification- as this tensor is not a result of any mathematical operation, you simply said you want this `b` tensor to `require_grad`.
IMO it is a user created `tensor` as it was placed (created) on graph for the first time (before there was no need for that as it didn't require gradient).

And **it does** have it's `requires_grad` set to `True`, you did it explicitly here.

#### Comment 3 & 4

> Everything with requires_grad=True is on the graph

Yes, but something with `requires_grad=False` can be on a graph as well if it is a leaf. Actually every PyTorch operation is created and added dynamically onto computational graph, here we use simplification: it's on graph if it takes part in `backpropagation`. For example neural network parameters are leafs yet they are on graph **as the last part during backpropagation** and they have their gradients (as they are optimized they need to be in graph in order to backprop through it).

> Everything not on the graph is a leaf

Yes, essentially

> everything on the graph that is not the product of operation on graph
> tensors is a leaf

Yes, if you add some `tensor` to it (e.g. created by `torch.randn` or such) is a leaf

> every leaf on the graph and non-leaf where I set retain_grad=True
> manually will get .grad attribute populated.

Yes, it if it is part of `backpropagation` which is almost always the case in our "mental graph" case (I think at least). Unless it already has `requires_grad=True`, in this case it will be populated with gradient. Basically, except for creation, you shouldn't tinker with setting `requires_grad=True` as it is prone to fail (as you saw) and will definitely raise some eyebrows for other people reading your code.

> every non-leaf on the graph has a `grad_fn` associated with it

Yes, that follows as some operation had to create it (and if it was created by some operation and this operation is differentiable, `grad_fn` is registered to be used during `backward()` call).

Comment: Thankk you! You have mentioned that creating the tensor with require_grad=False and then assigning other tensors to its slices would only change its is_leaf status - "So the only change here would be it will no longer be a leaf, but this would not break promises as .grad would be None anyway." But, I tried and I think the requires_grad is getting inherited from the slice and also .grad is available. ``` outi = torch.empty(2,requires_grad=False); outi[0] = out1; outi[1] = out2; print(outi.is_leaf, outi.grad_fn, outi.requires_grad) #output: False <CopySlices object at 0x7fd97d313370> True```

Comment: @MiloMinderbinder added an edit to clarify what I had in mind, hope it is clearer now

Comment: I'm running into all sorts of inconsistencies in the interplay between `.is_leaf`, `grad_fn`, `requires_grad`, `grad` attributes of a tensor. for example: ```a = torch.ones(2,requires_grad=False);
b = 2*a;
b.requires_grad=True;
print(b.is_leaf) #True```.. here b is neither user-created nor does it have its requires_grad True. According to definition this should not be a leaf variable then I guess. Why is `b.is_leaf` True then?

Comment: @MiloMinderbinder Once again added an edit with your example, hopefully it will be clearer this time. Agreed, it is confusing when you are going into it.

Comment: aahhh ... I was moving without a distinction between 'on graph' 'off graph' tensors in my mental framework. Once I start seeing tensors in conjunction with when they were placed on the graph, various attributes are certainly making MUCH more sense. Am I correct in summarising - "Only everything with requires_grad=True is on the graph" "Everything not on the graph is a leaf and everything on the graph that is not the product of operation on graph tensors is a leaf."  "every leaf on the graph and non-leaf where I set retain_grad=True manually will get .grad attribute populated." contd..

Comment: "every non-leaf on the graph has a grad_fn associated with it." Am I right in my understanding so far?

Comment: @MiloMinderbinder Yes, I think that is right, added next edit with details. "Graph" we are talking about is a little simplified but I think it helps in this case.

Comment: you have mentioned "Yes, but something with requires_grad=False can be on a graph as well if it is a leaf. " .. if requires_grad=False then it necessarily is a leaf. So what do you mean by "...if it is a leaf". you have also mentioned "it's on graph if it takes part in backpropagation." .. Isnt it that only if requires_grad=True then and only then it will take part in backpropogation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222839/discussion-between-szymon-maszke-and-milominderbinder).

Comment: I think `requires_grad=True` is essentially what all in graph is. https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-tensor-is-in-the-computation-graph/28886. I tried it using `make_dot` from `torchviz`. I used this toy code: ```a = torch.ones(2,requires_grad=True);
b = torch.tensor(2.,requires_grad=True)*a;
c*=torch.tensor(1.,requires_grad=True);
make_dot(c) #will show multipliers in the graph```.  As I changed the `requires_grad` flags in multipliers creation they disappeared from the rendered graph. Have I missed something?